# BC-2300 minary Reading Data Serial port and how to original string decode

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm reading data in BC-2300 using rs232 port C#

```
port.PortName = "COM3";
port.BaudRate = 9600;
port.DataBits = 8;
port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.Open();

private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    InputData = port.ReadExisting();

    if (InputData != String.Empty)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
    }
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
    this.textBox1.Text += text;
}
```

this is protocol files
https://uploadfiles.io/4e7au

And the output is like:

> P2A.,'? +,,??, ? ?k+- k??-+VVk? K,,+?K? ,, -V-?++K, ?, ,. +,?++,?K-VK-V+KVKK.+,++??+V+,+? - +-+ K+V? V VVV V ? ? ? V K ---? ++ +K +, ,.+,+?V?+,V?+?V?V+?+?+?V, , ,+,+,K,k,+++++--,+, ,+k, ??++V,,V+V,+,V,+V. ?. + k+ K---+ k+V? V VV? V ,? , -, ?,,,,.. --- ,,,,,,,X,,,,,p, - .,,?-,VV ? k+ K .+,,V+?V-+K,-VKKK V+V-V-V-VKK+VKV,,+-+?V?,V,+,.. k -K -- - ?-+++ - K ?  V? V   VV.,, ? ? , -, ???,,,..,.. ---- --- ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,?P?,-.,, V?  K+++ ?++,,?+V+k+,K?k,KK-V?Kk- V VKVkV-VK?V+V V+VkVKVKKkVKVK,K.+.V,V+?++,++--V+K?V??+V+VV,V+V?++,+?V,+,? ?. ,+ ++ k -- -- ???- ??--- k+VV VVVV? ? ? ? ? ? V    V V V V V VVVV? V V ? V V   VV..........,? ? ,,,,..V....,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,i

any one help me for how to convert original format

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The data *(or better to say the date and time)* you wrote is what did you read from port and now you want to convert it? Or Did you not receive any data? Or what is the problem. For conversion there is incorrect description a title. For reading there is a confusing title and missing question.

Comment: sorry for half response please check reponse https://oasis.sandstorm.io/grain/LSSxdteLzrmDpyYa484mvi

Comment: This is not a help, I see only: "You do not have permission to access this grain." Update your question to clarify the content, the real problem. You want `DateTime.ParseExact`, or some help with serial port reading? The first is duplicate of existing questions.

Comment: i reading data using serial port and reponse like this please open and see out put: https://oasis.sandstorm.io/grain/LSSxdteLzrmDpyYa484mvi

Comment: please see question i can edited output and thanks

Comment: It seems, like you received binary data, but display these as text. Unless you know, what type of binary data you got, it is not possible to tell what you should do.

Comment: actually this one is protocol for Bc-2300 manchine
https://ufile.io/4e7au

Comment: hello julo i share protoco files have you seen
https://uploadfiles.io/4e7au

Comment: As I see it, according to the protocol, you should not get this type of data. The problem can be in wrong communication parameters *(incorrect speed, data bits, stop bit etc.)*. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this device type.

Comment: thanks for your response but i can  match the every parameter like comport,baudrate,bit,handshake,parity etc.. and anything other method??

Comment: The last possible option, that I can think of is problem with communication speed. Once *(many years ago)*, I had seen a industrial computer with RS-232 ports on board. But there was a problem. The communication speed from application was incorrectly set to the port. It was double the speed, or half the speed. So when you set 19200 on PC, you need to set 38400 on device *(or 9600)*. The problem was in BIOS of the motherboard. We requested a fixed BIOS from the producer and problem was fixed. But it is unlikely this is you case.

Comment: In my experience, when I see garbage like this on the serial port it usually means your baudrate is set wrong.